# Is a continuous function with this property injective?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Suppose that I have a continuous $f$ in a topological space with the following property:

for every continuous $g$ and $h$ such that $f \circ g  = f \circ h$ $\Rightarrow$ $g=h$

It is true that a continuous $f$ with the property above must be necessarily injective?

I think that the easier approach is that one: One must show that if $f$ is not injective than it's possible to find continuous $g$ and $h$ such that $f \circ g  = f \circ h$ but $g \neq h$

But I have no idea how to construct such $g$ and $h$. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I made a mistake while writing the question, my apologise

Comment: Can you prove the same statement regarding sets and set maps between them ? (that is, no topology and no continuity involved)

Comment: Yes, I can do this

Comment: Homeomorphism is by definition injective.

Comment: Please change the word "homemorphism" in the title to "continuous function". The body has already been fixed, but not yet the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the space, and suppose that $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$, where $x_0\ne x_1$. Let $$g:X\to X:x\mapsto x_0$$ and $$h:X\to X:x\mapsto x_1\;.$$

Comment: It's very easy, It's like Maxime Ramzi said, the proof is simply a imitation of the function case, can't believe I don't drawn this solution myself , thank you so much.

Comment: @VictorRafael: You’re very welcome.